# Is the Clear Stick Atlas 4G USB modem stick compatible with Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, internet

A company named [Clear](http://www.clear.com) provides 4G internet services and sells devices for it, such as the [Clear Stick Atlas](http://www.clear.com/devices/details/id/devatlas/name/CLEAR-Stick-Atlas). That device is supposedly to work on Linux, Android™ and Chrome OS. They have a disclaimer that says that Linux, Android™ and Chrome versions must support Remote Network Driver Interface Service Specification (RNDIS) or Communication Device Class (CDC).

Has anyone had any luck with any of these firmware/drivers or devices purchased from Clear?

Comment: The USB stick is probably just a rebrand from a "real manufacturer", such as Huawei. Try to find out what kind of hardware this is under the Clear label and it will be a lot easier to find more information about it.

Answer (score 0):

*Has anyone had any luck with any of these firmware/drivers or devices purchased from Clear?*

The [FreedomPop Bolt, and Clear Stick Atlas are manufactured by Ubee Interactive WiMax device, model: PXU1964](http://www.ubeeairwalk.com/products/usb-dongles.html), which uses the Sprint's 2500 MHz frequency WiMax service.

A report says a [FreedomPop Bolt worked on a Debian variant](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=27654).

A report says the [Ubee PXU1964 works on an Android Nexus 10](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2099798).

A report says the [Ubee PXU1964 itself runs Linux](http://www.indigent-networks.com/?p=482).  The stick runs a web server, `nmap -O` says the TCP stack is running on Linux.